# Numerical integration of Tolman-Oppenheimer-Volkov equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I am reading this paper:
https://aip.scitation.org/doi/abs/10.1063/1.527511?journalCode=jmp

The author arrives to this equation:

[image: differential equation]

Then he says the solution looks like this:

[image: Graph of solution]

I am having trouble to follow this. If I use finite differences, I get the equation:

$$
\frac{y(x+\Delta x)-y(x)}{\Delta x}=\frac{(2x+9)y^2+18x(2x-1)y-8x^2(14x-3)}{2x(2x+3)y}
$$
Since the initial condition is y(0)=0, the scheme would fail at the first step, as the denominator is zero.

Does anybody have a clue on how to solve that equation?

EDIT:

Gaining some ground by doing this trick: in the product $yy'$, take $y=y(x+\Delta x)$. That way I get a new equation:

$$
y(x+\Delta x)=\frac{y(x)}{2}\pm\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{y(x)^2+4\frac{(2x+9)y^2+18x(2x-1)y-8x^2(14x-3)}{2x(2x+3)}\Delta x}
$$

But then I run into trouble near the first zero, where the discriminant goes negative.

(I am taking into account that $\Delta x$ becomes negative when $x'=y(x)<0$)

Any pointers?

Comment: Look for a power series $y(x) = 0 + a_0x + a_1 x^2 + \dots$ near $x = 0$ and find the first few coefficients.

Comment: Thanks Hans. But I don't know y(x), so how can I do that expansion?

Comment: @DrD Plug the series into the equation and leave only the biggest nonzero terms (probably they would be $O(x)$). As another approach you may try implicit numerical methods

Answer (score 1):

Actually the trick proposed on the EDIT works. But some modifications need to be introduced to the algorithm.

Let's re-define:

$$
y(x+\Delta x)=\frac{y(x)}{2}\pm\frac{s}{2}\sqrt{y(x)^2+4\frac{(2x+9)y^2+18x(2x-1)y-8x^2(14x-3)}{2x(2x+3)}\Delta x}
$$

$s$ is a sign parameter that starts as $s=1$.

When the discriminant<0, we need to reverse the direction of the steps, e.g. reverse the sign of $\Delta x$, and also reverse the sign of $s$.

Doing that, I am reproducing the solution reported in the paper:

[image: solution]